# how to read the url string of uploaded image in a view?

Tags: ios, swift, image, upload

this is the upload image function is inside the view

```
 private func persistImageToStorage() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: uid)
        guard let imageData = self.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.loginStatusMessage = "Failed to push image to Storage: \(err)"
                return
            }

            ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                if let err = err {
                    self.loginStatusMessage = "Failed to retrieve downloadURL: \(err)"
                    return
                }

                self.loginStatusMessage = "Successfully stored image with url: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                print(url?.absoluteString as Any)
              
                }
            }
        }
```

i want to read the url?.absoluteString in its view and all the functions within the view ? how can i extract that url?.absoluteString to be read ?

if you could kindly show me the way, thank you alot

Comment: Why don ‘t you save url in a property?

Comment: as url type save it in userdefaults  ?

Comment: If you want to save in UserDefault, save the absolute string.

Comment: i just wrote 
                let personimage = UserDefaults.standard.setValue(url?.absoluteURL, forKey: "personimage")  inside the function here, but can't read that personimage outside the function

Comment: Did you try absoluteString not absoluteUrl as I don’t think url can be stored in user default. Also be sure that the value you are storing is not null (using an optional it can be nil)

Comment: i am so sorry maybe i didn't make it clear, i want the image to be read outside the function and not just saved any idea ? so that if i want to call outside this function i can read it in another function or class, thus  it will be saved in user default and also read by another function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243232/discussion-between-ms-lightwave-and-ptit-xav).